# cuando quiero realizar animaciones desde javascript a una card de boopstraps, no me lo toma

Tags: javascript, jquery

**la idea seria que cuando haga click realice la animacion con jquery pero no pasa nada**

```js
const menupostre=() => {
 for (const postre of postres){
 let contenedor= document.createElement("div");
 contenedor.innerHTML = `<div class="card shadow mb-1 lg-3  bg-dark rounded" style="width: 18rem;">
 <h5 class="card-title pt-2 text-center text-primary">${postre.nombre}</h5>
 <img src="${postre.img}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
 <div class="card-body text-white-50">
 <p class="card-text text-white-50 description">${postre.descripcion}</p>
 <h5 class="text-primary">Precio:$${postre.precio}</h5>
 <div class="d-grid gap-2">
   <button class="btn1 btn-primary button " id="btn1" onclick=mostarcantidad()>Comprar</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>`
 document.getElementById('tarjeta').appendChild(contenedor);
 }
 }
**este es la animacion que deberia realizar con jquery al hacer click**
 $(".btn1").click(function(){

  $("card-img-top").animate ({
    transform:'360(deg)',
    height:'100px',
    opacity:'1',
    
})
 $("h5").css("color","darkgoldenrod")    
})
```

```html
 <div class="conteiner-fluid">
        <div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2  row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-3"  id="tarjeta">

        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debe verificar la propiedad css position del elemento padre, intente dejar el padre como relative y el contenedor para animar en absolut.